# Keep getting CANNOT GET /up everytime i request

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

i am trying to get the response from /up but i keep getting error saying `CANNOT Get /up` but, i can get other response apart from `/up`,

my route:

```
import {Application} from "express";
import {AuthenticationService} from
  "../authentication/application/authentication_repository";
import {TYPES} from "../core/types";
import {myContainer} from "../core/inversify_config";

export function routesConfig(app: Application) {
  app.get("/", (_req, res) => res.status(200).send("Hey there!"));

  app.post("/signup", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const {email, password} = req.body;
      if (password.toLowerCase == null || email.toLowerCase == null) {
        return res.status(400).send({message: "Missing fields"});
      }
      const authService = myContainer
          .get<AuthenticationService>(TYPES.AuthenticationService);
      console.log("after call the get injections");
      const uid = await authService.signUp(email, password);
      return res.status(200).send({uid});
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(400).send(error);
    }
  }
  );

  app.get("/up", (_req, res) => res.status(200).send("Hey!"));
}
```

index.ts:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import * as express from "express";
import * as cors from "cors";
import * as bodyParser from "body-parser";
import {routesConfig} from "./routes_config/routes_config";

const app = express();
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().functions);
admin.firestore();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cors({origin: true}));

routesConfig(app);

export const api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

i cant figure why `/up` keep getting error, but other is working fine, i even try to move the `/up` still yet, the error keep coming

[image]

Comment: Is the error "CANNOT POST /up" or "CANNOT GET /up"?  You've indicated both.  Where/how are you making the request?  Is there any additional error information on the browser console or in the network tab?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: @David the error is CANNOT Get /up

Comment: the only error i am getting is CANNOT Get /up@DanielA.White

Comment: @GbengaBAyannuga: Now is a good time to start familiarizing yourself with your browser's development/debugging tools.  In those tools you will find a console which may contain more information about the error, as well as a network tab which may contain more information about the request being made and the response being received.

Comment: @David, this is a plain get request. Browser console will not help much.

Comment: What response do you get at localhost:5001/uneleap-9b858/us-central1/api/?

Comment: @kost: If there's a specific HTTP response code from the server, that could certainly help.  It's counterproductive to take the approach that "debugging won't help us debug this".

Comment: Restarting my system solve it...